# how to find the index of as dict entery

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, indexing

I have searched every where to find the answer but i can only find how to get the index of the first value, i thought i could revers the values but then order gets messed up and i need it its order.

my problem is I have an empty array that gets filled with values from a .txt file. 
wich looks like this when printed:

`{1: '*', 2: '%', 3: '@', 4: '"', 5: '.'}`

i need to be able to find the index number of the second value e.g. `*` is `0` and `@`@ if `2`.

Comment: You have a dictionary, not a list. Dictionaries are *unordered*. There is no index to assign to anything.

Comment: You want to do reserve lookup in your dictionary, right? One solution is to construct another dictionary which uses the value as key and key as value.